# C# Writeline its not giving me the expected

Tags: c#, console.writeline

actualy its a basic question.
Im trying to read a CSV file and write in the console only the ones that includes the "Honda" word.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Vitor\Downloads\LogCombustivel.csv"));

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');
            if (values[0] == "Honda")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In this way, the console its not giving any results. 
But the basic way to show me all the results like as follow, its working

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Vitor\Downloads\LogCombustivel.csv"));

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line); 
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Any clues about what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want only lines that *start with* "Honda"?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: So I guess the answers below don't help. Can you post the actual CSV? (just a couple of lines)

Comment: It could be a lot of thing. Inspect the file carefully, or debug and inspect the array. One obvious possibility is that `values[0].Trim() == "Honda"` will be better.

Comment: You should consider using a library to read the CSV file, since the value could be quoted, etc. Also consider using `File.ReadLines` rather than `StreamReader` (which *should* be in a `using` block).

Answer (score 3):

The following code will only display a line if the first element is "Honda":

```
if (values[0] == "Honda")
{
}
```

That isn't right if you want to load every element that *contains* "Honda". You can use Linq's `Contains()` method for this.

Add the namespace for Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And use the following code instead, which will look in the array for any "Honda" element:

```
if (values.Contains("Honda"))
{
   // Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added linq query that searches for the string Honda.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Vitor\Downloads\LogCombustivel.csv"));

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');
        if (values.Any( x=> x == "Honda"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Array.IndexOf(values, "Honda") >= 0` or (with Linq) `values.Contains("Honda")` instead of `Any` with a predicate (`Func<,>`) that just checks for equality.